# Bitcoin not received from Coinmama to Blockchain Wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, blockchain.info

I made a small purchase from Coinmama and transferred it to my Blockchain wallet. It has been over two hours and it hasn't appeared. I'm relatively new to this, but it has never taken this long. Can anyone clue me in?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on amount of bitcoin you sent and fee you opted to pay will determine lenght of time for transaction. Network very busy and sets large transactions and people who pay the higher fees as priority.  It could take a little while. You can check status of transaction by checking blockchain. A few sites allow you to do this using your bitcoin address.